# Запуск и ожидание завершения другого приложения из GoLang

Tags: golang

Нужно запустить из своего приложения чужое (буду передавать путь к нему в качестве параметра) и когда оно завершиться - перезапускать его снова.
Как реализовать сам запуск с ожиданием на Go?

Answer (score 0):

Есть же в примерах в официальной документации: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Command

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.